# ngrx/store...is there a way to get the name of store slice being used?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Is there a way to get the name of store slice(accumulator)being used from inside the reducer?

e.g.

```
StoreModule.provideStore({
      books: BookReducer,
      magazines: MagazineReducer,
    })
```

I need to get the key 'books' inside the BookReducer

Comment: Why do you need the key? The reducer should see only the value associated with the key; it should not be concerned with anything else.

Comment: I guess it is very case specific, I am creating a dynamic service that is responsible for adding data in the store, syncs with the remote database and handles offline storage. The service receives the store slice name upon initialization and the rest is done automatically. Now, I want to pair this with a dynamically created reducer that has the basic add/update/delete functions but since when calling dispatch all reducers get the action i need to prefix the actions i.e. add_books or add_magazines so I need to be able to get the slice name from within the reducer to use it as the prefix.